# Find which places are using strings that are not in the strings.xml

Tags: android, string, android-studio

What is the command in Android studio to know which places are using strings directly? Strings that are not in the `strings.xml` file

Answer (score 4):

You can use either:

- `CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + I`
- Analyze -> Run Inspection by name.

And look for *hard coded strings*

[image]